# ReportService2005 FindItems by parameter with boolean data type

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services

I've added a boolean parameter called *IsNewReport* to **some** of my reports and I'm trying get a list of these reports using the SSRS web service (ReportService2005.asmx).

But I keep getting an exception thrown by the web service "The IsNewReport field has a value that is not valid."

So how should I setup the SearchCondition to find my reports?

Heres an example of the webservice call:

```
var reports = ReportingService2005.FindItems("/MyReports",
    BooleanOperatorEnum.Or, GetSearchConditions());
```

And here's an example of the GetSearchCondition method

```
private static SearchCondition[] GetSearchConditions()
{
    List<SearchCondition> conditions = new List<SearchCondition>();

    SearchCondition searchCondition = new SearchCondition();

    searchCondition.Condition = ConditionEnum.Equals;
    searchCondition.ConditionSpecified = true;
    searchCondition.Name = "IsNewReport";
    searchCondition.Value = "true";

    conditions.Add(searchCondition);

    return conditions.ToArray();
}
```

PS I've tried this code changing the property name to "Name" and a value matching the name of one the existing reports and this works without exception,.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've got it - you can't use FindItems to search though a reports parameters only the properties of the report. "Name" worked because it's a property of the report where as IsNewReport is a parameter that I've added to the report.